# How to copy Google Form with Google Spreadsheet to new owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need help fixing a script.  Currently I have a script that enables me to copy a sheet from a master form.

**Problem:**
If I have a form linked to the sheet, the script does NOT copy the form. I want to copy the form and link to each sheet copy.

---

I have found a [wonderful app script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6yM229Lo_M&feature=youtu.be) (thanks to youtuber Carl Arrow Smith) that enables me to copy a sheet from a master form yay!  This is the code:

```
function copyfilefromsource() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var sheet_merge = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
  var last_row = sheet_merge.getLastRow();

  var newsheet_firstname = null;
  var newsheet_surname = null;
  var newsheet_email = null;
  var source_folder = null;
  var file_owner = null;
  var dest_folder = null;
  var sheets_created = 0;
  var new_file = null;
  var source_file = null;
  var student_id = null;
  var google_domain = null;
  var range = sheet_merge.getRange(1, 1, last_row, 4);
  var temp = null;

  source_file = DriveApp.getFileById(range.getCell(1, 2).getValue()); //gets the source file to copy  
  dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(range.getCell(2, 2).getValue()); //gets the ID of the folder to place the copied files into
  file_owner = range.getCell(3, 2).getValue(); //person to own the files
  google_domain = range.getCell(4, 2).getValue(); //extension of the email address 

  if (last_row <= 6) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No rows to process!");
    return
  }

  for (var i = 7; i <= last_row; i++) { // loop to go down evenery row from 7 until the end
    if (range.getCell(i, 4).getValue() == '') { //makes sure there is nothing in the column, i.e. can run the script with some students already been processed if it fails half way through.
      student_id = range.getCell(i, 1).getValue(); //take the first column for the     
      newsheet_email = student_id + google_domain; //combines with username with the domain; 
      // should add some user checking code here!!!!! and only run the below if user exists (future improvement)

      newsheet_firstname = range.getCell(i, 2).getValue(); //gets first name from the sheet
      newsheet_surname = range.getCell(i, 3).getValue(); //gets surname from the sheet

      new_file = source_file.makeCopy(source_file.getName() + " - " + newsheet_firstname + " " + newsheet_surname + " - " + student_id, dest_folder);
      new_file.setOwner(file_owner); //allocates an owner to the sheet
      new_file.addViewer(newsheet_email); //allocates a viewer to the sheet
      //new_file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); //adds anyone with the link as a viewer

      //source_folder.removeFile(new_file); // hides from root folder  not required as going directly to correrrect folder
      // new_file.setActiveSheet('My Grades');
      //new_file.getRange(2,3).setValue(student_id);

      //change the a cell in the copied spreadsheet to the student ID 
      //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(new_file.getId());
      //var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // "access data on different tabs"
      //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('My Grades');
      // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      // ss.getRange('C2').setValue(student_id);

      //Add the details that the process has worked
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + new_file.getUrl() + '/","' + student_id + '")');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 4).setValue(new_file.getId());

      sheets_created++; // add to spreadsheets created
    }
  }
  ui.alert(sheets_created + " files were created!")
}
```

---

However I have a form Linked to the sheet and this script did not copy the form.

I want to copy the form and link to each sheet copy.

The App script essentially links to a sheet.  The source file and folder are added to a sheet.  Each time you type a persons name and first part of email into the sheet (copy below) it will create a copy of the sheet.  My question is how do I add to the script to get the form link to copy.

Link to my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lIu8eqnlPVX78r3JwFkCrgBQdBYunbcSFAIz_fP5iII/edit#gid=0)

---

I found a second script on StackOverflow which looks to address a similar issue ([Copying Google Spreadsheet no longer copies linked Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454803/copying-google-spreadsheet-no-longer-copies-linked-form)) and I've tried adding script to it but the reality is 48 hours later I've just made a mess and not advanced at all.

1st post on here so go easy on me if i've not given enough info.
thanks

End result needs to be form and link to copy with the sheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying Google Spreadsheet no longer copies linked Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454803/copying-google-spreadsheet-no-longer-copies-linked-form)

Comment: I've added that link as part of my research.  How do I incorporate that code re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454803/copying-google-spreadsheet-no-longer-copies-linked-form      into the following app script code     link to sheet which has app script attached and a copy dummy file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lIu8eqnlPVX78r3JwFkCrgBQdBYunbcSFAIz_fP5iII/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Welcome. Please explain your problem in more detail. I ran your script and it works. For a spreadsheet with one or more linked forms, the spreadsheet is renamed in accordance with the code AND any/all linked forms **ARE** copied and the forms **ARE** linked to the newly copied spreadsheet. The file name of copied forms is prefixed with "Copy of" but the form title is unchanged. It's possible to change ownership of the spreadsheet to the new user, but I found that the form owner does not change. But a different coding approach might make it  possible to change the owner of the forms as well.